# Why does PagedListPager with ajax replacing enabled reload the page on page selection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I wanted the pagination to happen asynchronously but the complete page reloads on selecting a page. Can anyone please tell me how to make the pagination happen asynchronously?

Here's the code.

```
@Html.PagedListPager(listData, page => Url.Action("ViewOnMap", new { search, Beds, Baths, minprize, maxprize, page, IsSearch, SearchFilterBy }),PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod="GET", UpdateTargetId= "DivPropertyOnMap" }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use this. You could use something like this.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList

```
public IPagedList<listData> getdata(int? Page, int? pageIndex)
{
   ...
   return data.OrderByDescending(x => x.OnSave).ToPagedList(Page ?? 1, pageIndex ?? 10);
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult List(datamodel model)
{
    var dataModel = new getdata(model.Page, 10);
    return View("_dataList", dataModel );
}
```

Razor list.cshtml

```
 <div id="listdata">
  @Html.Partial("_List", @Model)
</div>
```

_list_cshtml

```
@model youdatemodel
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;

<ul>
@foreach (var item in Model.dataModel)
{
   <li>
      @item.dataitem;
   </il>
}
</ul>


@Html.PagedListPager(Model.modeldata, page => Url.Action("List", new RouteValueDictionary
{
    {
        "Page",page
    }
}), PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "listdata" }))
```